# How to convert this shape/equation into a Parametric Equation please?

Tags: parametric, desmos

From my understanding, but please correct me if I am wrong, this equation is implicit (See the attached screenshot).

However, the goal is to create an identical (**or similar**) shape that is defined using "**parametric** equations". Is there any good way to do that please? Thank you for the help.

In addition, if it is possible to configure this shape to be in the direct "**center**" of the graph (instead of being on the side), that would be even better.

In summary:

- Define this shape (does not have to be identical, just needs to be similar) using parametric equations
- Plot the equation/shape to be in the center of the graph (symmetrical by the y-axis)

Thank you for any advice or help.

[A bean-shaped equation modelled in Desmos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vnws.png)

Comment: Small part of an answer: This equation sets it more "in the center of the graph":
$$
\left(x^{2}+\ \left(y^{2}+ay\right)\right)^{2\ }=\ a^{2}\left(y+\frac{a}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you, wow! That is genius! I do not know how you figured that math out, but that equation is exactly the idea I have in my mind.

Specifically, if a1 is set to = 4, and a2 = 9, and a3 = 1... that gives the overall shape to be very similar to what I showed originally. Thank you.

Comment: Now somehow need to convert this implicitly-defined equation into a parametrically-defined equation.

Comment: That "conversion" is really not at all straightforward, unfortunately.

Comment: Here's a kinda-sorta-looks-a-little-like-what-you-want answer: $(x(t), y(t)) = (\cos(t),\sin(t)\ - 0.4 \cos(2t))$

Comment: Thank you. That is very smart. I have tried to modify the coefficients of that original equation to something like this: (x(t), y(t)) = (1.53cos(t), 0.99sin(t)+0.42cos(2t))... HOWEVER, the shape is quite different from what I showed originally in the implicitly defined equation. Now, this equation is indeed explicitly defined, but its shape, specifically the "rounded-ness" of the "heart-shape" is lacking

Comment: Yeah...I'm pretty sure I can do a lot better, but I need a few free hours to make that happen, and I don't have those right now.

Comment: And here's an insane numerical approximation that looks pretty good to me: `y(t) = .0097 + .7070* cos(t) + .0608 * cos(2*t) - 0.1004 * cos(3*t) + .0350*cos(4*t) + .0012 * cos(5*t) - .0114 * cos(6*t) + .0092 * cos(7*t);` 
`x(t) = .8946 * sin(t)  - .0222*sin(2*t) - .0872 * sin(3*t) + .048 * sin(4*t) - .0146 * sin(5*t) - .0016 * sin(6*t) + .0066 * sin(7*t);`

Comment: GENIUS!!! That is absolutely brilliant. I plotted this equation, and it is literally identical to the shape that I am aiming for. Thank you. This is amazing. Mr. John Hughes with the Huge help. Thank you. By the way, do you offer these help on StackExchange out of your own generosity? I see that you are in the top 0.21% of all users (that is 99th percentile, top 1%, incredibly impressive). If you want, I would like to compensate you for your time and effort. I can transfer a small amount as a thank you gift, if you want.

Comment: @C_Y Would this work as well: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/svfyf34ql3

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plot of an approximation (with x and y axes swapped):
[image: a plot of the bean curve, and its approximation by a fourier series in magenta diamonds]
The actual code that produced the magenta diamonds in that plot was

```
kx = .0097 + .7070* cos(t) + .0608 * cos(2*t) - 0.1004 * cos(3*t) +
 .0350 * cos(4*t) + .0012 * cos(5*t) - .0114 * cos(6*t) + .0092 * cos(7*t);

ky = .8946 * sin(t)  - .0222 * sin(2*t) - .0872 * sin(3*t) + .048 * sin(4*t) - 
.0146 * sin(5*t) - .0016 * sin(6*t) + .0066 * sin(7*t);
```

Here $t$ should run from $0$ to $2*\pi$.

That was produced by several steps.

1. For each of 100 values values of t (call them $t_1, t_2, \ldots$) between $0$ and $2\pi$, I let $x = r \cos(t_i)$ and $y = r \sin(t_i)$ and then adjusted $r$ until $(y^2 + (x-1.2)^2 + 1.2*(x-1.2))^2 - 1.2^2 *(x - \frac{1.2}{2})$  was approximately $0$ using bisection on the range $0 \le r \le 2$. Call the resulting values of $x$ and $y$ by the name $x_i$ and $y_i$. Each pair $(x_i, y_i)$ was a point of the curve, or at least very close to it. The blue line-graph was created by connecting the dots using these points.
2. This got me a vector $X = \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\...\\x_{100}}$ and a corresponding vector $Y= \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2\\...\\y_{100}}$. For an arbitrary pair of vectors of 100 entries, I defined a 'dot product' $u \cdot v = \frac{1}{100} \sum_{i = 1}^{100} u_i v_i$.
3. I noticed that the function $x(t)$ that I was looking for had the property that $x(t) = x(-t)$ and that $x(t + 2\pi) = x(t)$; that meant that $x$ could be written as a sum of cosines of various frequencies. Similarly, because $y$ has the property that $y(t) = -y(-t)$, $y$ could be written as a sum of sines. So supposing that $x(t) = a_0 cos(0t) + a_1 cos(1t) + \ldots + a_7 cos(7t)$, I created vectors $C_k = \pmatrix{\cos(k t_0) \\ \cos(kt_1)\\ \dots \\ \cos(kt_{100})}$ and similarly for $S_k$, but with sines.
4. I computed
   \begin{align}
   a_0 &= C_0 \cdot X\\
   a_1 = 2 C_1 \cdot X\\
   \ldots
   a_7 = 2 C_7 \cdot X
   \end{align}
   and similarly
   \begin{align}
   b_0 &= S_0 \cdot X\\
   b_1 = 2 S_1 \cdot X\\
   \ldots
   b_7 = 2 S_7 \cdot X
   \end{align}
   The factor of 2 (and its missing on $a_0, b_0$) comes from considering sines and cosines of negative frequencies as well). As it happens, $b_0$ is always zero anyhow, because $S_0$ is the zero vector.
5. These numbers are the coefficients that I wrote in the formulas for $kx$ and $ky$ above.

The secret sauce here is "numerical approximation of the fourier transform of a continuous even (or odd) function on the circle" if you want to go read up on why this is the right way (or "a right way") to get here. Here's some very ugly matlab code that implements all this:

```
function mse4792658
clf;

N = 100;

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, N+1);
t = t(1:end-1);
x = zeros(N,1);
y = x;

j = 1;
for theta = t
    c = cos(theta);
    s = sin(theta);
    g = @(r) f(r*c, r*s);
    rr = findroot(g, 0, 2);
    x(j) = rr*c;
    y(j) = rr*s;
    j = j + 1;
    g(rr);
end
plot(x, y, '-b');
set(gca, 'DataAspectRatio', [1, 1, 1]);
figure(gcf);

K = 7; 
for n = 0:K
    cbasis = cos(n*t);
    sbasis = sin(n*t);
    cc(n+1) = dot(cbasis, x)/N;
    cs(n+1) = dot(sbasis, y)/N;
end
cc(1) = cc(1)/2; 
x = @(v) dot(cc, cos( (0:K) * v));
y = @(v) dot(cs, sin( (0:K) * v));
xx = zeros(N, 1);
yy = xx;
for i = 1:N
    xx(i) = x(t(i));
    yy(i) = y(t(i));
end
hold on;
plot(2*xx, 2*yy, '.r');
figure(gcf);
hold off;
'cc'
disp(cc)
'cs'
disp(cs)

kx = .0097 + .7070* cos(t) + .0608 * cos(2*t) - 0.1004 * cos(3*t) + .0350*cos(4*t) + ...
.0012 * cos(5*t) - .0114 * cos(6*t) + .0092 * cos(7*t);
ky = .8946 * sin(t)  - .0222*sin(2*t) - .0872 * sin(3*t) + .048 * sin(4*t) - ...
.0146 * sin(5*t) - .0016 * sin(6*t) + .0066 * sin(7*t);
hold on;
plot(kx, ky, 'dm');
hold off;

function u = f(x, y)
a = -1.2;
p1 = (y^2 + (x-a)^2 + a*(x-a))^2;
p2 = a^2 * (x - a/2);
u = p1 - p2;

function u = f2(x, y)
u = (x-0.3)^2 + y^2 - 1;
```